# Send message on user's behalf after the user has clicked a button

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I would like to know if it is possible to send messages on behalf of the user after a specific event? In my case I want to be able to see the user's response in the chat after he has already clicked a button from one of the suggested actions which by default gets hidden after that.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Edit:

Sorry for the confusion. What I meant was basically kind of "faking" a real user message which will contain just the button text. So basically if we have this example: [image]

I would like to have a message in blue (on behalf of the user) which states either red, green or blue, depending on the user's choice.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's probably possible, but without further elaboration we won't be able to assist you with this

Comment: _"send messages on behalf of the user"_ - to what/who/where? your bot? something else?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Please, see my edited question

Comment: Are you using Web Chat v3 or v4? This is much easier in v4.

Comment: @tdurnford I am using v4 but could not find documentation related to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no trick to this. You already seem to know how to use suggested actions, but you say the "default" behavior is for the message to be hidden after the user selects it. That is only true for the `postBack` action type. If you use `imBack` or `messageBack` then you can have the selected message persist in the conversation history. With `imBack` the displayed message will be the action's `value` property and with `messageBack` the displayed message will be the action's `displayText` property.

[image: imBack]

[image: messageBack]

You can create suggested actions from card actions using an activity's `SuggestedActions` property or with `MessageFactory.SuggestedActions`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted! I don't know why it's so hard to find information about this. 

There is only one downside when using this approach - you can't use complex objects and can only return strings to the bot but I can live with that.

Thank you once again!

Comment: @K.Todorov - Some channels do provide the ability to send visible text along with invisible data in the same card action. The Bot Framework refers to this as a messageBack. In Web Chat, the messageBack's `text`, `value`, and `displayText` are all used. The card action's `text` and `value` are used to populate the properties of the same name in the activity, and the `displayText` is used in Web Chat's displayed conversation history as you've seen.